# Mug and wireframe entirely disappeared

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

I accidently hit something and wireframe mode is gone. I'm now in what looks like cycles render, but I cant escape out of it.

[image]

My mug is nothing but a grey shadow basically. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You have turned your viewport shading to "Rendered".

[image]

In order to edit your mesh, you need to switch to either

- Material
- Textured
- Solid
- Wireframe

Solid should be the default mode and is the most common mode for editing.

You can use shortcuts to switch between modes:

<kbd>Z</kbd> --- Wireframe

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> --- Render View

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> --- Texture View

Answer (score 2):

You are in rendered mode. Rendered mode does not show vertices, edges or faces.

Switch back to wireframe or solid shading.

[image]